# How to open setting from our application in xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**I am working on xamarin.forms.** (Facing below problem only in android)

When my application is started it checks my GPS location is on or off.

To check GPS location on or off I am using dependency service.

```
public static bool CheckGPSConnection()
        {
            var gpsConnection = DependencyService.Get<IGPSConnectivity>();
            return gpsConnection.CheckGPSConnection();
        }
```

When I come to Home page of my application I put following code

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{
    if (!App.CheckGPSConnection())
    {
        bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Would you like to start GPS?", "Yes", "No");
        if (answer)
        {
              Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings));
        }
    }
}
```

but it's giving me an exception

> {Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from
>   outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want?   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in /Users/…}

**What should I do?**

Comment: If you're using Forms you probably want to use `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context`

Comment: var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @Dineshkumar as already pointed out in the error message itself ('Is this really what you want?'), that is not ideal.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context not found

Comment: That is weird, it should be there. In what project is this code anyway? The Droid project right? Or are you working with a Shared project instead of a PCL?

Comment: I am working in PCL with xamarin.forms not native.

Comment: Instead of this line `Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings));` this line `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings));` should be working.

Comment: Yes, I found in dorid project, not in PCL. So to access in PCL I have to make dependency service. right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142601/discussion-between-gerald-versluis-and-rutul-mehta).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is platform specific functionality, so you should create a DependencyService for it.

Just like for the `IGPSConnectivity` create another interface. For example `ISettingsService`.

```
public interface ISettingsService
{
    void OpenSettings();
}
```

Then on Android, implement it like this:

```
public class SettingsServiceAndroid : ISettingsService
{
    public void OpenSettings()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocat‌​ionSourceSettings));
    }
}
```

Now call it from your shared PCL code, again, just like with the GPS connectivity one.

`DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().OpenSettings();`

Because you are using the DependencyService, the right implementation per platform will be injected. So, there is no need for the `if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)` line, unless you did that for another reason of course. Also, I think this method is now [deprecated](http://motzcod.es/post/159463651162/device-os-xamarin-forms-obsolete-runtime-os). You should now use `Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android` as of Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.

Comment: If you get namespace problems use "global::" prefix:   global::Android.Content.Intent

Answer (score 0):

In Android I use this (calling with DependencyServices) to open Settings

```
    public void View(){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

        if (locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider) == false)
        {
            Intent gpsSettingIntent = new Intent(Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(gpsSettingIntent);
        }
    }
```