# Opening Location Settings Page or Prompting user to Enable Location

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i've been hacking my brain and googling away in vain. i am trying to find a way to prompt the user to switch location on either by going directly to the settings page or just tapping yes on the screen.
all code i've seen doesn't seem to work. does any one have something that works. a detailed example will be much appreciated. thank you. 
I'm really new to Xamarin development

i would prefer a way to do it on xamarin forms, but starting with something that will prompt android user, because for iOS i have no simulator

[image: this page]
[image: or this].

Comment: What do you mean "switch location"? Do you mean turn location permissions on for your app?

Comment: I mean Turn Location Service On Or Off  on **the Settings of the Device ** NOT the App

Comment: @lalith i cant see your comments anymore

Comment: Can anyone please guide me

Comment: I've added images to show what i mean.. If I get either of the above will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so after going through several tutorials and answers all over the internet i finally was able to find to accomplish what i wanted to achieve,

i used a dependency service as one of the answers indicated here [How to open setting from our application in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608067/how-to-open-setting-from-our-application-in-xamarin-forms?answertab=active#tab-top)

there are few things that were not mentioned like registering the interface in order to use it in platform specific projects.

here is the code for anyone who needs it

**the Interface :**
I called my Interface ILocSettings.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DE2.ILocSettings))]
namespace DE2
{
    public interface ILocSettings
    {
        void OpenSettings();

    }
```

the form that has a button I called it DataEntryForm

**DataEntryForm.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DE2.DataEntryForm"
             >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <Button x:Name="TurnLocationOn"
                    Text="Turn On Location"
                    Clicked="TurnLocationOn_OnClicked"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

then the **DataEntryForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Plugin.pbXSettings;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using Plugin.DeviceInfo;
using Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DE2.ILocSettings))]

namespace DE2
{

    using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DataEntryForm : ContentPage
    {
        public DataEntryForm ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

        }


        private async void  TurnLocationOn_OnClicked(object sender, global::System.EventArgs e)
        {

            var myAction = await DisplayAlert("Location", "Please Turn On Location", "OK","CANCEL");
            if (myAction)
            {
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == global::Xamarin.Forms.Device.Android)
                {

                    //DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().OpenSettings();
                    global::Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<global::DE2.ILocSettings>().OpenSettings();



                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Device", "You are using some other shit", "YEP");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert","User Denied Permission","OK");
            }


            // 
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this Class Placed on the Android Specific Platform **LocationZ.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using DE2;
using DE2.Droid;


//[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ILocSettings))]

//Notice the use of LocationZ in registering below instead of ILocSettings

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(LocationZ))]

namespace DE2.Droid
{
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;

    using Android.Support.V4.View;
    using Android.Support.V7.App;

    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using DE2;


    public class LocationZ : ILocSettings
    {
        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            LocationManager LM = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);


            if (LM.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider)==false)
            {


                            Context ctx = Forms.Context;
                            ctx.StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings));


            }
            else
            {
                //this is handled in the PCL
            }
        }


    }
}
```

`

Comment: Swap `Forms.Context` for `Android.App.Application.Context`, `Forms.Context` is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about getting the user to grant location permission, the easiest way to do it is to use the permissions plugin. This allows you to both request and check on a particular permission.

[The permission plugin and full documentation can he found here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)

You will then be able to do the following:

```
try
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
        //Best practice to always check that the key exists
        if(results.ContainsKey(Permission.Location))
            status = results[Permission.Location];
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000);
        LabelGeolocation.Text = "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
    }
    else if(status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    LabelGeolocation.Text = "Error: " + ex;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but what i need is for the user to be prompted to Enable Location Service either by just pressing yes somewhere or by going to the Location Settings page and enable location.  as for the above example i had already done that and its working , but it works only when the location in the device is already enabled. the extra feature i want for my App is to ask the user to switch on location service when its off

Comment: Has anyone accomplished this in Xamarin forms... Even if it works on android only but the solution is multi-platform

Comment: I found the Solution, i will share later today when am off work. thanks to all who contributed, i had to use a mix of things

Answer (score 0):

[image: First]

[image: Third]

the Images show the screens up to the Settings page