# Xamarin forms: Location permission alert is not showing in iPhone device

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, location

I have added the location permission feature in my project and the permission alert is working fine on ios simulators. But in a real iPhone device, permission is not asking.

I have added the location permissions in the info.plist file like below.

[image]

The app settings page shows all the other permission details except the location.

[image]

My Code:

```
public async void ShareLocation()
{
    var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        //Actions
    }
}
```

Reference: [Xamarin Forms: How to check if GPS is on or off in Xamarin ios app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940855/xamarin-forms-how-to-check-if-gps-is-on-or-off-in-xamarin-ios-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 13, Apple made a big changes in location permission’s behaviour, especially for **Always Allow** permission.

In Xamarin.Forms you could use the plugin [Permissions Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) from nuget .

#### Usage

```
try
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<LocationPermission>();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
        }

        status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<LocationPermission>();
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        //Query permission
    }
    else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
        //location denied
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Something went wrong
}
```

By the way , what is the iOS version on your real device ? The key **Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description** is available after iOS 10.0 .Use this key if your iOS app accesses location information while running in the background. If your app only needs location information when in the foreground, use **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** instead.

Comment: My ios version is 14.3

Comment: Add the line `using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;`

Comment: Added the using statements, still an error:  Error CS0104 'PermissionStatus' is an ambiguous reference between 'Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus' and 'Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus'

Comment: `using PermissionStatus = Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus;`  Showing this as a suggestion, should I add it?

Comment: Yes , add it and the error will disappear .

Comment: Same result. This code is also working fine in android but not showing the permission alert in ios (both simulator and real device)

Comment: I have added 2 keys in info.plist: `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` and `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`. I need location details when the app is in the foreground or background.

Comment: My problem is the location permission alert(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgAbm.png) is not showing and the location permission entry is not listing on the app properties page(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD3Lw.png).

Comment: Re-install the app and test again .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227373/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).