# Xamarin always loud push notifications

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to send push notifications to the users of my app, the notifications should always be loud no matter if the user has it's phone (Android & iOS) silent, on vibrate or loud.

My app is for alerting volunteer firefighters, so the users are downloading the app in order to get alerts.

Is this possible with Xamarin and how? Because i didn't find something regarding this problem in the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can Instead use an alarm, it would play the sound always even if the phone is silent

Answer (score 0):

No you can't send push notifications to the users of your app, the notifications should always be loud because Android/IOS has Some restriction to Developer but you can try Alarm Manager it may help help you code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460571/xamarin-alarmmanager-android)

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done as iOS and Android has srestrictions to stop all aps doing this.

The only work around is to tell your users to turn on do not disturb and then ask them to make your app an exception in their do not disturb settings. There may be a way to do this programatically or at least open the correct settings pages programatically.

EDIT:

You can open settings pages programatically however it is platform specific:

[How to open setting from our application in xamarin.forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608067/how-to-open-setting-from-our-application-in-xamarin-forms)